# R.Shiny Convert an input into a string of characters

Tags: r, string, datatable, containers

In my shiny I have an input:

```
  selectInput(inputId="VarC",
              choices=choices_Var,
              multiple = T),
```

Then, in my container I'm trying to use the input as character for the header:

```
sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
      class = 'display',
      thead(
        tr(
          th(colspan = 1, 'First'),
          th(colspan = 2, 'Second'),
          th(colspan = 3, as.character(input$VarC))))
```

But it doesn't work.
I think that even with as.character my input isn't a string and that's why it doesn't work :/
I have this error:
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Do someone know how to do it ?

Comment: No puedes usar un elemento reactivo `input$VarC` fuera de una función reactiva, para este tipo de situaciones existen las funciones `reactive()`, las `render...`. En tu caso deberías consultar `renderUi( )`

Comment: Thank you. But are you sur of this ? I think that what i'm searching for is a function which could make abc -> f(abc) = "abc" no ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification

```
sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
      class = 'display',
      thead(
        tr(
          th(colspan = 1, 'First'),
          th(colspan = 2, 'Second'),
          th(colspan = 3, textoutput("text"))))
```

In the app server add this

```
output$text <- renderText(as.character(input$VarC))
```

Anyway, try to add a reproducible example of your app, just with the elements involved in your problem. This help other to help you.